# @Autowire within a DTO object - produces NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

On a spring boot  2.4.3 application with Java:

I am using a DTO to construct the JSON response from the domain model of the application. The DTO is just a plain java object.

I am trying to property inject a new class that I created for data transformation using the @Autowired but I get a nullPointerException on the runtime.

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class FetchSupplierDTO {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String info;
    private List<String> tags;

    @Autowired
    private TagTranslation tagTranslation;

    public FetchSupplierDTO(SupplierEntity supplier) {
        this.id = supplier.getId();
        this.name = supplier.getDisplayName();
        this.description = supplier.getGivenDescription();
        this.info = supplier.getInfo();

        if (supplier.getTags() != null) {
            this.tags = tagTranslation.extractTagsFromEntity(supplier.getTags());
        }
     }
}
```

---

```
@Service
public class TagTranslation {

    public List<String> extractTagsFromEntity(List<TagEntity> tagEntityList) {
        List<String> tagStringList = new ArrayList<>();
        tagEntityList.forEach(productTag -> { tagStringList.add(productTag.getTag()); });
        return tagStringList;
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you want your dto to contain such logic, in my understanding dto are pure pojos. But anyway, The autowire will not work if you create your dto object with the new  operator

Comment: Did you try having your FetchSupplierDTO  being a Component. Also, include the line: 
@ConditionalOnBean({TagTranslation.class}) on it. Also, as H4x9r pointed out, if you are creating the object of your dto with new operator, Autowired is not going to work.

Comment: Can you share the stacktrace? In fact, looking at your method from `TagTranslation`, it can pretty much be an Utils static method instead of something you would want to inject.

Comment: ```@Component
@ConditionalOnBean({tagTranslation.class}```
does not solve the issue, neither the ```this.tags```  is causing the NPE since it is a List which is assigned to it a List as a return from the method

Answer (score 1):

First of all, looking at the current code I would design it so that the caller of the constructor is responsible for calling the autowired service. Then the DTO really stays a DTO and is not at the same time responsible for calling a service.

If there is really no way around calling a Spring component from inside a DTO then you will have to get the component manually. And call `SpringBeanLocator.getBean(TagTranslation.class)` to get that component and insert it in your field.

Spring holds a single instance of each component, on initialization it scans for autowired annotations within annotated classes (@Component, @Service) and initializes those fields. Once you call the constructor of such a class separately, it will not return the instance that is maintained by Spring, it will construct a new instance. Therefore it's autowired fields will be null.

```
public class SpringBeanLocator implements ApplicationContextAware {

  private static ApplicationContext context;

  @Override
  public final void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) {
    validate(getInternalContext());
    setContext(context);
  }

  public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> type) {
    context.getBean(type);
  }
}
```